# NumPy elementwise chaining comparison (a <= b <= c)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python support chaining comparison:

```py
1<2<3<4
```

How to do that for NumPy?

If only 3 array, we can do this:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
b = np.array([2,6,1,5,6])
c = np.array([7,4,6,6,8])
np.logical_and((a <= b),(b <= c))
```

With 4 array, it becomes too burdensome since `np.logical_and` only accept 2 inputs.

```py
a = np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
b = np.array([2,6,1,5,6])
c = np.array([7,4,6,6,8])
d = np.array([8,9,9,9,2])
np.logical_and((a <= b),(b <= c))  # work
np.logical_and((b <= c),(c <= d))  # work
np.logical_and((a <= b),(b <= c),(c <= d))  # not work
```

---

Edit:
Slightly add complexity, on 2D:

```py
a = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([[2,6,3],
              [1,5,6]])
c = np.array([[7,4,3],
              [6,6,8]])
d = np.array([[8,9,3],
              [9,9,2]])
```

Comment: @QuangHoang tested, the axis should be `axis=0` I think. I didn't check if `np.all` support axis and I just learn it today. Thanks

Comment: Benchmark of answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914783/11671779).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `&`:

```
(a <= b) & (b <= c) & (c <= d)
```

As the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) says:

> The `&` operator can be used as a shorthand for `np.logical_and` on boolean ndarrays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) method from `functools`.

```
import functools
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,4,5,6])
b = np.array([2,6,1,5,6])
c = np.array([7,4,6,6,8])
d = np.array([8,9,9,9,2])

arr = [a <= b, b <= c, c <= d]
result = functools.reduce(np.logical_and, arr)
```

**EDIT**

There's a cleaner way, proposed in the comments.
Reduce method is already part of [`ufunc`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html#numpy.ufunc.reduce) in `numpy`. Using it removes the need for additional imports. We can change the last line of the example above the following way.

```
result = np.logical_and.reduce(arr)
```

Comment: `ufunc` have a `reduce` method.

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**:

Use Kelly Bundy answer. No need for more import. Even work without importing `numpy` by yourself if you got the array for other package.

If only 3 array, use OP answer.

**Explanation**:

After running the test again and again, all three (OP, AndrejH, and Kelly Bundy) results is fast and inconsistent which one is the best. Someone with better profiler can do better benchmark.

---

**Benchmark**:

```
import functools
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,100))
b = np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,100))
c = np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,100))
d = np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,100))
```

```py
# arbitrary number of chains
%timeit (a <= b) & (b <= c) & (c <= d)
%timeit functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [a <= b, b <= c, c <= d])
%timeit np.logical_and.reduce([a <= b, b <= c, c <= d])
%timeit np.all([a<=b, b<=c, c<=d], axis=0)
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: all(arr[1:] >= arr[:-1]), 0, np.stack([a, b, c, d]))
```

```
1.02 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
930 µs ± 93.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.09 ms ± 11.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.52 ms ± 360 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.1 s ± 276 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```py
# only up to three array
%timeit (a <= b) & (b <= c)
%timeit functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [a <= b, b <= c])
%timeit np.logical_and.reduce([a <= b, b <= c])
%timeit np.all([a <= b, b <= c], axis=0)
%timeit np.logical_and((a <= b), (b <= c))
%timeit np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: all(arr[1:] >= arr[:-1]), 0, np.stack([a, b, c]))
```

```
927 µs ± 457 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
559 µs ± 25.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
733 µs ± 39.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
819 µs ± 42.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
585 µs ± 40.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
1.01 s ± 69.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

**OLD BENCHMARK**

Chaining (best: AndrejH)

```py
%timeit functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [a <= b, b <= c, c <= d])  # AndrejH
6.27 µs ± 244 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.all([a<=b, b<=c, c<=d], axis=0)  # Quang Hoang
59.7 µs ± 8.37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Chaining up to three array (best: OP)

```py
%timeit np.logical_and((a <= b), (b <= c))  # OP
3.8 µs ± 339 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit functools.reduce(np.logical_and, [a <= b, b <= c])  # AndrejH
4.2 µs ± 75.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit np.all([a <= b, b <= c], axis=0)  # Quang Hoang
45.6 µs ± 6.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks. The `± 234 µs` is pretty large variation. Is it really that erratic, or maybe your computer was just more busy at that time? Maybe try it a few more times.

Comment: @KellyBundy Consistent benchmarking is hard using local computer with only small time different. Any suggestion?

Comment: Not sure. I do a lot of benchmarking with Python, but not with NumPy and not with `%timeit`.

Comment: how about `np.logical_and.reduce`?

Comment: @hpaulj Added. It seems slower in my test, but roughly the same. Maybe because it needs to find `reduce` from `np.logical_and`. Using `nplar = np.logical_and.reduce` also not helping at all.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, you can stack the arrays and check if each column is sorted.

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda arr: all(arr[1:] >= arr[:-1]), 0, np.stack([a, b, c, d]))
# array([ True, False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: Can you explain it better? Confused here.

Comment: This one can have an easier loop in generating the stacked value. But, sladly, slower.

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is basically an iteration over all dimensions except the one that's being passed to the function.  It is NOT a performance tool.